# Finding a closed formula for the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1-(\frac{i}{n})^2}$

Tags: summation, asymptotics, estimation

Consider the sum: $F(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1-(\frac{i}{n})^2}$.

So far I found these upper and lower bounds using the well known sum-integral inequality:

- $F(n)\geq1+\int_{1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^{2}}\text{ d}x\geq\frac{n}{2}\log(2n-1)-O(\frac{1}{n})$
- $F(n)\leq\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{2}}+\int_{0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^{2}}\text{ d}x\leq\frac{n}{2}\log(2n-1)+O(n)$

I am trying to find a close formula for $F$, or at least to find a function $G$ such that: $$F(n)=\frac{n}{2}\log(2n-1)+G(n)+o(1)$$

I would guess $G=\Theta(n)$ but it is a pure guess based on looking at graphs...

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, the question is of course equivalent to estimating $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n^2-i^2}$

Comment: A simple asymptotics is $$
F(n) = \frac{n}{2}H_{2n}  + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{n}{2}\log (2n) + \frac{n}{2}\gamma  + \frac{3}{8} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right).
$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{n^2}{n^2-i^2}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{n^2}{(n-i)(n+i)}=\frac n2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac1{n-i}+\frac1{n+i}\right)=\frac n2\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\frac1k+\frac1n\right)=\frac{nH_{2n-1}+1}2\;,
$$

where $H_n$ is the $n$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) with

$$
H_k=\log k+\gamma+\frac1{2k}+O\left(\frac1{k^2}\right)\;,
$$

where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant). Thus

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{n^2}{n^2-i^2}
&=&
\frac12\left(n\log(2n-1)+n\gamma+\frac n{2(2n-1)}+1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)
\\
&=&\frac n2\log(2n-1)+\frac{n\gamma}2+\frac58+O\left(\frac1n\right)
\\
&=&\frac n2\log(2n)+\frac{n\gamma}2+\frac38+O\left(\frac1n\right)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: You will need one more term from the asymptotics to get an error of the form $o(1)$ requested by the OP.

Comment: @Gary: True, thanks, I wrote that out.

Comment: $\gamma$ has to be multipled by $n$ as well. Note that you can write $F(n)$ in terms of $H_{2n}$ (see my comment above) so you do not really need to manipulate the asymptotics.

Comment: @Gary: True, fixed.

Comment: (+1) I got the same thing, but I like $\frac n2H_{2n}+\frac14$. Just an aesthetic preference.

Comment: @robjohn: Nice – I agree :-)

Comment: Thats perfect, thanks!